# задать значения dataframe в виде списка из значений следующих n строк подряд

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

предположим имеется датафрейм следующего вида:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list('abcde'))
'''
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  e
```

Для каждой строки необходимо взять текущее значение и значения из n следующих за ней строк и добавить это в датафрейм в виде списков. То есть, для n=2 должно получиться так:

```
'''
0    [a, b, c]
1    [b, c, d]
2    [c, d, e]
```

у меня это получилось сделать, но решение мне не очень нравится:

```
pd.concat([df.shift(-i) for i in range(3)], axis=1).dropna().apply(list, axis=1)
'''
0    [a, b, c]
1    [b, c, d]
2    [c, d, e]
dtype: object
```

пробовал еще так, но это нравится еще меньше:

```
df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.name:x.name + 2, 0].to_list(), axis=1)
'''
0    [a, b, c]
1    [b, c, d]
2    [c, d, e]
3       [d, e]
4          [e]
dtype: object
```

Как еще это можно сделать? Может как-то с помощью `rolling`?

Comment: Rolling может получиться, попробуйте

Comment: @CrazyElf, пока не получается. Нагуглил вот [это](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23002). Похоже, что со строками rolling не работает.

Comment: Ага, я до того же догуглился. Похоже да, `rolling` пока только для чисел можно, увы. А вариант с шифтами мне кажется не так уж и плох, должен довольно быстро работать.

Comment: rolling в принципе можно использовать для строк df['new'] = [x.values.tolist() for x in df[0].rolling(3)]

Comment: @ДимаВиноградов, не знал, что rolling генерирует объекты DataFrame и Series, спасибо. Проитерировать можно, но вот rolling-функции (тот же rolling.apply) со строками почему-то не работают(

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант с использованием *more_itertools* и *itertools*.**

*(Не совсем "по-пандовски")*

```
from more_itertools import windowed
from itertools import chain


df = pd.DataFrame(list('abcdefghij'), columns=['col'])

def consecutive(column, n: int):
    col_to_list = df[column].to_list()
    pad = [None] * n
    return [list(filter(None, i)) for i in windowed(chain(col_to_list, pad), n=(n + 1))]
```

На вход данной функции подается название столбца и "Ваш" ***n*** (как Вы указали в примере).

```
df['new_col'] = consecutive('col', 2)
print(df)

>>>  
  col    new_col
0   a  [a, b, c]
1   b  [b, c, d]
2   c  [c, d, e]
3   d  [d, e, f]
4   e  [e, f, g]
5   f  [f, g, h]
6   g  [g, h, i]
7   h  [h, i, j]
8   i     [i, j]
9   j        [j]
```

Comment: забавно оказывается у меня уже установлен модуль `more_itertools`, надо бы познакомиться с ним поближе.

Comment: там много интересных фишек! ;)

Comment: да я уже оценил. Полезная вещь.